# Is it correct to implement a custom NgbDateParserFormatter to change the format of the input value on NgbInputDatepicker?

Tags: angular, momentjs, ng-bootstrap

I'm using the datepicker ([ng-boostrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io)) in a popup and I would like to change the date format to `dd-mm-yyyy`.

It seems that it can be solved by implementing a new `NgbDateParserFormatter` to replace the default `NgbDateISOParserFormatter`.

But I was wondering if there is another way.

**UPDATE:**

A small implementation of `NgbDateParserFormatter` using Moment.js
(tested with version 1.0.0-alpha.14 of ng-bootstrap):

```
import {NgbDateParserFormatter, NgbDateStruct} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import * as moment from 'moment';

export class NgbDateMomentParserFormatter extends NgbDateParserFormatter {
    constructor(private momentFormat: string) {
        super();
    };
    format(date: NgbDateStruct): string {
        if (date === null) {
            return '';
        }
        let d = moment({ year: date.year, 
                         month: date.month - 1, 
                         date: date.day });
        return d.isValid() ? d.format(this.momentFormat) : '';
    }

    parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct {
        if (!value) {
            return null;
        }
        let d = moment(value, this.momentFormat);
        return d.isValid() ? { year: d.year(), 
                               month: d.month() + 1, 
                               day: d.date() } : null;
    }
}
```

And in a module, you include the provider using a factory to indicate the date format as a parameter:

```
---

@NgModule({

  ---

  providers: [
    { 
      provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, 
      useFactory: () => { return new NgbDateMomentParserFormatter("DD-MM-YYYY") } 
    }
  ]

  ---

})
```

Comment: Be aware - moment expects to have zero indexed months. Your code fails on every day of december.

Comment: Thanks @David, I fixed the code. When I posted the code, NgbDateStruct was using zero indexed months too, but that changed later.

Comment: @Nelson I tried your approach. I have added providers in the core module of my application to change date format of my date picker component. Its not working. Help me out.

Comment: @MohanRam Could you share your code?

Comment: Note that, in a more recent Angular 4 version, useFactory on providers no longer exists. Use: useValue: new NgbDateMomentParserFormatter("DD-MM-YYYY") instead

Comment: as of today, this still works with @HammerNL's fix. Thanks!

Comment: Your update content worked perfectly for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As of today implementing a custom `NgbDateParserFormatter` is the best way to go. So yes, it is a correct way.

In the future we might have a more sophisticated implementation of the `NgbDateParserFormatter` where you will be able to just pass a desired format (ex. `yyyy-MM-dd`). Adding this feature will depend on user's interest.

You might also check some more background info in https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/754#issuecomment-247767027

Comment: I am also wondering how I can change the formate on the dates, would it be possible to add a simple example of how to implement the `NgbDateParserFormatter` without moment.js I simply want to be able to reformat the date.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource How should this answer be changed if we are using AOT compilation?  

I have tried `export function NgbDateMomentParserFormatterFactory() {
    return new NgbDateMomentParserFormatter("DD-MM-YYYY");
}`

and 

 `providers: [
    { 
      provide: NgbDateParserFormatter,
      useFactory: NgbDateMomentParserFormatterFactory
    }]`

but that doesn't seem to apply the changes.

Comment: Do not use a factory when using AOT Compiler. Try this example:https://gist.github.com/nrobinaubertin/61ff1c3db355c74f4e56f485b566ab22

Comment: Although it works on a clean project, it didn't work for my fairly big app (lots of modules importing each others...) with Ng5 and AoT compilation (JiT works but it's not an option for me). Is there an other way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Create custom parser formatter.

```
import { NgbDateParserFormatter, NgbDateStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class NgbDateCustomParserFormatter extends NgbDateParserFormatter {

  format(date: NgbDateStruct): string {
    return date ? `${isNumber(date.day) ? padNumber(date.day) : ''}-${isNumber(date.month) ? padNumber(date.month) : ''}-${date.year}` : '';
  }
}
```

Set the provider for the custom parser formatter in the @NgModule.

```
providers: [
    {provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: NgbDateCustomParserFormatter}
]
```

As described in the [api](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#NgbDateParserFormatter)