# Angular2 Bootstrap Datepicker format date issue

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I have issue with overriding NgbDateParserFormatter
I followed steps from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39546645/ng-bootstrap-is-it-correct-to-implement-a-custom-ngbdateparserformatter-to-chan) but it doesn't work for me. Look like that app doesn't override original `NgbDateParserFormatter`.

My app structure looks like this:

```
|-app/
|--app.module.ts
|-- datepicker/
|---datepicker.component.ts
|---ngb-datepicker-parser-formatter.ts
|--login/
|---login.module.ts
```

I have imported `ngb-datepicker-parser-formatter.ts` in app.module and login.module. I am using datepicker.component in another component wich is lazy loaded with login.module.
My app.module looks like this:

```
 @NgModule({
  ---
  imports: [
    ---
   NgbModule.forRoot(),
   ---
   ],
  providers: [
   ---,
   { 
     provide: 'NgbDateParserFormatter', 
     useFactory: () => { return new NgbDateMomentParserFormatter("DD-MM-YYYY")}
   }],
    ---
 })
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the quotation marks around NgbDateParserFormatter?