# How to set date format in input of ng bootstrap

Tags: angular, date-format, ng-bootstrap

I am using **[ng bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker)** datepicker. I want to set date format in input tag.
This is my html code

```
<input (click)="d.toggle()" type="text" [formControl]="updateEventForm.controls['live_date']" 
  value="{{dispalyLiveDate | date: 'd/M/yy'}}" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
```

Here `{{dispalyLiveDate | date: 'd/M/yy'}}` is my default value, when select date then date format is convert to `yyyy-M-dd`, i want this date format same as `d/M/yy`
I had read document and find method `format(date: NgbDateStruct)` but don't know how to use it.
Is it possible to convert default date format direct into input tag(without convert into component) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39546645/ng-bootstrap-is-it-correct-to-implement-a-custom-ngbdateparserformatter-to-chan

Comment: I have check this document, but from that i can not understand how to implement it ? What changes need to be done in `component` and `HTML` ?

Answer (score -1):

If you have the date with whatever format, you can paint it in the format that interests you in the html using this:

```
{{order.flight.date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

where 'order.flight.date' is the object where the date is stored.

It is important for this not to fail that the format is not the same that we want to obtain in any case.

I have not found a way to format the date to the desired format before storing it without doing it manually:

```
  // Analyze and change the date format
  parseDate(date) {
    let result = date;
    if (date != null) {
      if (date instanceof Date === false) {
        const parts = date.split('/');
        result = new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

The language i am using is Angular 5.

In ngx-bootstrap you can specify the format:

```
<input
        class="form-control"
        [minDate]="minDate"
        [maxDate]="maxDate"
        #dpYMD="bsDatepicker"
        bsDatepicker
        formControlName="myDateYMD"
        [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD' }">
```

Comment: The OP is asking about ngb-datepicker, not ngx-datepicker.