# configurable date format for Angular 2 datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker

My project is running angular 2 with ng-bootstrap. I need to implement a datepicker where I can configure the date format that it renders into the input field.

I know there's some automatic functionality in the browser that will format it according to localization the user, but we're looking for more control than that.

I've been reading up on datepicker formatting, and it seems it's not supported without some customization.

[ng-bootstrap: Is it correct to implement a custom NgbDateParserFormatter to change the format of the input value on NgbInputDatepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39546645/ng-bootstrap-is-it-correct-to-implement-a-custom-ngbdateparserformatter-to-chan)

Unfortunately, neither time nor ng2 skill level is on my side. I'm really hoping for a plugin that can handle this.

This is the closest I've found:

[Angular 2 Material 2 datepicker date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452966/angular-2-material-2-datepicker-date-format)

I'm reading the second answer: "From documentation:" not familiar enough with angular 2 to know where to put the CONST or the export date format.