# Change datatapicker yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy/mm/dd to ng-bootstrap-angular2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

i am using ng-bootstrap on my project with Angular4, but i have a small problem, the format that show the input when i chose a date is yyyy-mm-dd, i need to show the date chose in format yyyy/mm/dd, to change  "-" => "/".

I belive that don't is so much problem, but i don't find how fix it.

Someone can help me? please.

thank.

Comment: The tag you have to use is angular  NOT angularjs

Comment: It is apparently a current issue: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/754

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-bootstrap: Is it correct to implement a custom NgbDateParserFormatter to change the format of the input value on NgbInputDatepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39546645/ng-bootstrap-is-it-correct-to-implement-a-custom-ngbdateparserformatter-to-chan)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39546645/ng-bootstrap-is-it-correct-to-implement-a-custom-ngbdateparserformatter-to-chan

Comment: Thank you! That's solved the problem :D

Comment: I am new in Angular >.<